# MDP concerning two states systems

Tags: stochastic-processes

[image: Both systems]

A system can take only two states 1 and 2. We wish to compare two decisions D1 and D2 causing transitions between these two states. Each of these decisions entails given costs (in €) in the following table:

[image: Costs table]

In the long term what is the best decision?

Here is my work:

I deduced the following transition matrices:

T1 = [0.22 0.78; 0.78 0.22]
T2 = [0.78 0.22 ;0.22 0.78]

Since T1 and T2 are ergodic, they admit respectively unique fixed points Q1o [1/2 1/2; 1/2 1/2] and Q2o [1/2 1/2; 1/2 1/2].

Can we deduce that D2 is more expensive knowing that both systems have the same chance of having status 1 or 2 and that the respective sums of costs are 25 and 27?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a reward / cost structure and decisions (i.e. actions)associated with your system. A Markov Chain would not be sufficient to explicate this. You can achieve this by modelling it as a Markov Decision Process.

In a nutshell, A Markov Decision Process (MDP) model contains:

- A set of possible world states S
- A set of possible actions A
- A real valued reward function R(s,a)
- A description T of each action’s effects in each state.

For an intro, take a look at Wikipedia and [here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Silver/web/Teaching_files/MDP.pdf).

Comment: OK, thanks, but what about my answer?

Comment: Your question is: given this reward and State-Action transition structure what is the best policy (that maximizes (future) rewards)? My pointer is you need to model the problem as an MDP - not as a Markov Chain. I unfortunately cannot view the figures you have posted as they are blocked by my company's firewall. Maybe wait and see if someone does actually sit down with a pen and paper and give you a full solution.